# Remove extra group level using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to remove the extra group level in my generated output. My requirements is that, I need to split the data in element `<FFF>` for every 10 characters. My code is almost working but it populated an extra group level `<FinalRecord>`. Here is my XML File:

**INPUT**

```
<RootParent>
<Data>
    <DetailRecord>
        <AAA>6</AAA>
        <BBB>22</BBB>
        <CCC>000000CC</CCC>
    </DetailRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>This is only for testing. I repeat. This is only for testing</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
</Data>
</RootParent>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT**

```
<RootParent>
<Data>
    <DetailRecord>
        <AAA>6</AAA>
        <BBB>22</BBB>
        <CCC>000000CC</CCC>
    </DetailRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>This is on</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>ly for tes</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>ting. I re</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>peat. This</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF> is only f</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>or testing</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>. This is </FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
        <FinalRecord>
            <FFF>only</FFF>
        </FinalRecord>
    </FinalRecord>
</Data>
</RootParent>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<RootParent>
<Data>
    <DetailRecord>
        <AAA>6</AAA>
        <BBB>22</BBB>
        <CCC>000000CC</CCC>
    </DetailRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>This is on</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>ly for tes</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>ting. I re</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>peat. This</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF> is only f</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>or testing</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>. This is </FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
    <FinalRecord>
        <FFF>only</FFF>
    </FinalRecord>
</Data>
</RootParent>
```

**MY XSLT CODE**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="FFF">
    <xsl:analyze-string regex=".{{10}}" select=".">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <FinalRecord>
                <FFF>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </FFF>
            </FinalRecord>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <FinalRecord>
                <FFF>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </FFF>
            </FinalRecord>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there something wrong or missing in my code? I'm stuck and don't know what to do. I tried to insert the `<xsl:template match="FinalRecord"/>` after the `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` to delete the record `<FinalRecord>` in the XML file and it didn't work. I am using the XSLT v2.0.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**

Element `FinalRecord` is processed by the "identity-copy-template" because there is no other matching rule.

---

> I tried to insert the `<xsl:template match="FinalRecord"/>` after the `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` to **delete** the record  in the XML file and it didn't work.

**Deleting** is kind of wrong. You need to process the element BUT just without creating the same element once again.

See this:

```
<xsl:template match="FinalRecord">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```